# How to declare a variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to declare a variable in mysql, so that my second query can use it?

I would like to write something like:

```
SET start = 1;
SET finish = 10;

SELECT * FROM places WHERE place BETWEEN start AND finish;
```

Comment: Don't forget you may need "Allow User Variables=True".

Answer (score 928, accepted):

There are mainly three types of variables in MySQL:

1. **[User-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) (prefixed with `@`):**

   You can access any user-defined variable without declaring it or
   initializing it. If you refer to a variable that has not been
   initialized, it has a value of `NULL` and a type of string.

   ```
   SELECT @var_any_var_name
   ```

   You can initialize a variable using `SET` or `SELECT` statement:

   ```
   SET @start = 1, @finish = 10;
   ```

   or

   ```
   SELECT @start := 1, @finish := 10;

   SELECT * FROM places WHERE place BETWEEN @start AND @finish;
   ```

   User variables can be assigned a value from a limited set of data
   types: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string,
   or NULL value.

   User-defined variables are session-specific. That is, a user
   variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other
   clients.

   They can be used in `SELECT` queries using [Advanced MySQL user variable techniques](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/).
2. **[Local Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) (no prefix) :**

   Local variables needs to be declared using `DECLARE` before
   accessing it.

   They can be used as local variables and the input parameters
   inside a stored procedure:

   ```
   DELIMITER //

   CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(var1 INT) 
   BEGIN   
       DECLARE start  INT unsigned DEFAULT 1;  
       DECLARE finish INT unsigned DEFAULT 10;

       SELECT  var1, start, finish;

       SELECT * FROM places WHERE place BETWEEN start AND finish; 
   END; //

   DELIMITER ;

   CALL sp_test(5);
   ```

   If the `DEFAULT` clause is missing, the initial value is `NULL`.

   The scope of a local variable is the `BEGIN ... END` block within
   which it is declared.
3. **[Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-system-variables.html) (prefixed with `@@`):**

   The MySQL server maintains many [system variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html) configured to a default value.
   They can be of type `GLOBAL`, `SESSION` or `BOTH`.

   Global variables affect the overall operation of the server whereas session variables affect its operation for individual client connections.

   To see the current values used by a running server, use the `SHOW VARIABLES` statement or `SELECT @@var_name`.

   ```
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%wait_timeout%';

   SELECT @@sort_buffer_size;
   ```

   They can be set at server startup using options on the command line or in an option file. 
   Most of them can be changed dynamically while the server is running using `SET GLOBAL` or `SET SESSION`:

   ```
   -- Syntax to Set value to a Global variable:
   SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size=1000000;
   SET @@global.sort_buffer_size=1000000;

   -- Syntax to Set value to a Session variable:
   SET sort_buffer_size=1000000;
   SET SESSION sort_buffer_size=1000000;
   SET @@sort_buffer_size=1000000;
   SET @@local.sort_buffer_size=10000;
   ```

Comment: Somehow ````=```` operator didn't work for me. It worked fine when I used ````:=```` operator.

Comment: `=` operator only works in `SET` clause. For assigning value to a variable in `SELECT` query you can use `:=` operator e.g. `SELECT @start := 1`

Comment: Can you please clarify what does this mean: "No need to declare User-Defined Session variables denoted with prefix @" ?

Comment: @billynoah I'm assuming it means that User-Defined Session variables (which begin with @) do not need an explicit declaration; you can just assign to them immediately as if they had already been declared.

Comment: Omesh: can you please explain what you mean when you say: "No need to declare User-Defined Session variables denoted with prefix @".

Comment: @MattO'Brien You can access any user-defined variable without declaring it or initializing it and you don't need to declare them explicitly. You can check my edited answer for more detailed explanation.

Comment: `User-defined variables are session-specific. That is, a user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients.` Does it mean that even if I have a `PHP PDO connection` and many `HTTP clients` reusing the same persistent connection, if the same PHP script executes the same query for two clients, they will both have different `User-defined variables`?

Comment: And you can assign a variable with the result of a select statement like this: SET @subscriptionId = (select subscriptionId from User where emailAddress='ac@tmail.com');

Comment: There is 4th variables type - status variables. They does not act like variables, but they are variables in terms of Reference Manual.

Answer (score 72):

> SET

```
SET @var_name = value;     /* or */     SET @var_name := value;
```

both operators **=** and **:=** are accepted

---

> SELECT

```
SELECT col1, @var_name := col2 from tb_name WHERE "condition";
```

if multiple record sets found only the last value in `col2` is kept (override);

```
SELECT col1, col2 INTO @var_name, col3 FROM ...
```

in this case the result of `Select` is not containing `col2` values

---

Ex both methods used

-- TRIGGER_BEFORE_INSERT --- setting a column value from calculations

```
...
SELECT count(*) INTO @NR FROM a_table WHERE a_condition;
SET NEW.ord_col = IFNULL( @NR, 0 ) + 1;
...
```

Comment: What is the difference between `=` and `:=`?

Comment: I guess that for mysql SELECT syntax is necessary to separate the meaning of = (comparation) from := (asign)

Comment: In certain cases, the values left in variables might NOT correspond to the last row returned.  For example, `SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(@var:=Name,'unknown') FROM Customers ORDER BY <some non-indexed expression> LIMIT 10` appears to evaluate the variable assignments before the order-by is done, so that the returned value of @var might not even relate to any of the returned rows.  The docs don't say under what conditions this can happen, though.

Answer (score 26):

Use **set** or **select**

```
SET @counter := 100;
SELECT @variable_name := value;
```

---

example :

```
SELECT @price := MAX(product.price)
FROM product
```

Answer (score 17):

Different types of variable:

- **local variables** (which are not prefixed by @) are strongly typed and scoped to the stored program block in which they are declared. Note that, as documented under [DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html):

DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

- **User variables** (which are prefixed by @) are loosely typed and scoped to the session. Note that they neither need nor can be declared—just use them directly.

Therefore, if you are defining a stored program and actually do want a "local variable", you will need to drop the @ character and ensure that your DECLARE statement is at the start of your program block. Otherwise, to use a "user variable", drop the DECLARE statement.

Furthermore, you will either need to surround your query in parentheses in order to execute it as a subquery:

> SET @countTotal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nGrams);

Or else, you could use SELECT ... INTO:

> SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @countTotal FROM nGrams;

Answer (score 11):

- Declare:
  `SET @a = 1;`
- Usage:
  `` INSERT INTO `t` (`c`) VALUES (@a); ``

Comment: `t` for table and `c` for column?

Comment: @carloswm85 yes

Answer (score 5):

For any person using @variable in concat_ws function to get concatenated values, don't forget to reinitialize it with empty value. Otherwise it can use old value for same session.

```
Set @Ids = '';

select 
  @Ids := concat_ws(',',@Ids,tbl.Id),
  tbl.Col1,
  ...
from mytable tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use semicolons between variable declarations, here is an example that worked for me using phpMyAdmin. In this way, we have to declare variables with every query we run.

```
[![Using Variables with mySql][1]][1]
```

---

```
SET @solicitud = 1;
SET @despacho = 1;
SET @recibe = 2;
SET @entrega = 123;
SET @firma = 'ABCD';
SET @equipo = 1124;
SET @sim = 123;
SET @fecha = '2023-07-07 13:43:20';

INSERT INTO `avl_equipo_tecnico` (`eqt_solicitud`, `eqt_equipo`, `eqt_usuario`, `eqt_despacho`, `eqt_fecha_registro`, `eqt_usuario_registro`, `eqt_situacion`) VALUES (
@solicitud,     -- solicitud 
@equipo,    -- equipo = ane_equipo 
@recibe,    -- usuario que recibe
@despacho,  -- despacho = ane_despacho
@fecha,     -- = ane_fecha_registro
@entrega,   -- el mismo que el anterior
'1'     -- situacion =1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give my awnswer here so people can try, solution for MySql that i think is easyer to understand:

```
set @countVal =  (select count(*) from STATION);
/**
499/2 = 249,5 -> 250 -- ceil
499/2 = 249,5 + 1 = 250,5 -- floor 250

500/2 = 250 -- ceil 250
       = 250 + 1 = 251 -- flor 251
**/       
set @ceilVal = ceil(@countVal/2);
set @floorVal = floor( (@countVal/2) + 1);
SELECT ROUND(AVG( latitude ),4) FROM
(SELECT @lineNum:= @lineNum + 1 as id, 
lat_n as latitude
FROM STATION s, ( SELECT @lineNum :=0 ) pivot
ORDER BY lat_n) as a
WHERE id IN ( @ceilVal, @floorVal );
```

Answer (score -2):

### SET Value

```
 declare @Regione int;   
 set @Regione=(select  id from users
 where id=1) ;
 select @Regione ;
```