# Difference between DECLARE and SET in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, set, declare

What's the difference between DECLARE and SET using SQL (or more specifically MySQL)?

Both can set variables it seems. I have read the MySQL docs and I did not understand the difference between the two.

Comment: `DECLARE` declares it and `SET` initializes it.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/declare-a-variable-in-mysql) Similar Post

Comment: @TimSchmelter So both DECLARE and SET are needed unless you use "DEFAULT" with DECLARE?

Comment: @YoubarajSharma: but the other question does not explain the difference between DECLARE and SET. It is just about the `DECLARE` syntax (rtfm-questions are off-topic on SO anyway).

Comment: @YoubarajSharma Actually that's the thing brought me here. I also read the manual pages that were linked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`DECLARE` does not initialize the variable. When you declare it you declare the variable name, the type, and a default value, which could be an expression.

`SET` is for initializing the variable you declared previously, and you cannot SET the variable until you DECLARE it.

Comment: Thank you! So you have to use both when creating a variable with a value unless you use "DEFAULT". Understood.

Comment: `you cannot SET the variable until you DECLARE it` not sure about version then, but we can't use `DECLARE` outside a stored procedure to declare a variable. We directly use `SET @newVar := 213` to declare as well as initialize

Answer (score 9):

`DECLARE` defines the variable type and `SET` initializes the variable.

```
DECLARE @Var1 INT;
DECLARE @Var2 INT;
SET @Var1 = 1;
SET @Var2 = 2;
```