# How to run SQL like EVAL in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have a query and its result is like:

```
myQueryValue
select * from 'some path'
```

I'd like to use it directly in new query.

```
SELECT someValue
FROM
(
    select * from 'some path' <- How can I replace this to myQueryValue?
)
```

How can I use the result value of some queries like EVAL?

----------------EDITED AT 14th Oct.----------------

Thanks for all answer but I need to explain more what I want.

If I have a 'queryTable' like

| col |
| --- |
| 'select * from tableA' |

The result of 'select * from tableA' is

| foo |
| --- |
| bar |

When I only know about 'queryTable', how can I get the this result?

| foo |
| --- |
| bar |

I'd like to refer 'queryTable', and get the final result of its.

Comment: Please provide more details and what exactly you want to achieve. You are using BigQuery UI or you want to use some APIs? It's for your script? Not sure if you want [Declare](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare) or [Set](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#set) or maybe [subqueries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries). Can you provide scenario?

Comment: Check out the examples under `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in the documentation.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate . You can create a SQL string and then execute that string as SQL.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late to reply. Thanks for all but I can't get the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub queries, its a query inside the from clause.

Here is an example code:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE SALARY > 4500)
```

> A Subquery or Inner query or a Nested query is a query within another
> SQL query and embedded within the WHERE clause.
>
> A subquery is used to return data that will be used in the main query
> as a condition to further restrict the data to be retrieved.
>
> Subqueries can be used with the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE
> statements along with the operators like =, <, >, >=, <=, IN, BETWEEN,
> etc.
>
> There are a few rules that subqueries must follow −
>
> Subqueries must be enclosed within parentheses.
>
> A subquery can have only one column in the SELECT clause, unless
> multiple > >columns are in the main query for the subquery to compare
> its selected > >columns.
>
> An ORDER BY command cannot be used in a subquery, although the main
> query >can use an ORDER BY. The GROUP BY command can be used to
> perform the same >function as the ORDER BY in a subquery.
>
> Subqueries that return more than one row can only be used with
> multiple >value operators such as the IN operator.
>
> The SELECT list cannot include any references to values that evaluate
> to a >BLOB, ARRAY, CLOB, or NCLOB.
>
> A subquery cannot be immediately enclosed in a set function.
>
> The BETWEEN operator cannot be used with a subquery. However, the
> BETWEEN >operator can be used within the subquery.

[click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm) for more information about sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

Below is example of how easy to achieve this

```
DECLARE myQueryValue STRING;
SET myQueryValue = "select * from your_table";

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT someValue
FROM ( ''' || myQueryValue || ''' )''';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide additional information I'm going to elaborate my comment.

In comment I've proposed that you can use [Declare](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare) with [Set](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#set). Good differences between those two are presented in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073646/).

> `DECLARE` does not initialize the variable. When you declare it you declare the variable name, the type, and a default value, which could be an expression.

> `SET` is for initializing the variable you declared previously, and you cannot SET the variable until you DECLARE it.

One of the examples has been provided in `@Mikhail Berlyant` answer in this thread.

However, more detailed information with more examples are mentioned in [GCP Set Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#set).

> Sets a variable to have the value of the provided expression, or sets multiple variables at the same time based on the result of multiple expressions.
>
> The `SET` statement may appear anywhere within the body of a script.

This is the easiest way to achieve this.

Another common way you could do this is to use `SubQuery/Nested Query`, it's also well described in the [GCP BigQuery Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries).

In GCP doc you can also find example which uses `Set`, `Declare` and `subquery`:

```
DECLARE target_word STRING DEFAULT 'methinks';
DECLARE corpus_count, word_count INT64;

SET (corpus_count, word_count) = (
  SELECT AS STRUCT COUNT(DISTINCT corpus), SUM(word_count)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare
  WHERE LOWER(word) = target_word
);

SELECT
  FORMAT('Found %d occurrences of "%s" across %d Shakespeare works',
         word_count, target_word, corpus_count) AS result;
```

Output:

```
Found 151 occurrences of "methinks" across 38 Shakespeare works
```