# MySQL could not to define variables with DECLARE

Tags: mysql

in mysql editor i can not define simple variables with `DECLARE` such as:

```
DECLARE v_delay INT DEFAULT 0 ;
```

i get this error now:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE v_delay INT DEFAULT 0' at line 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can only declare in a function, procedure, trigger, event, ....

You need a shell around your code if it is more than a query