# MySQL passing of values

Tags: mysql, variables

I am new to MySQL. I would like to ask how to pass the result of a select statement to a variable. The variable will then be used in succeeding queries (`CASE WHEN` or `IF ELSE`).

sample query:

```
select count(*) from table;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare a variable in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/declare-a-variable-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use user-defined variables, e.g.:

```
select count(*) into @itemCount from table;
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! My dilemma now is how to use the value inside [at]itemcount in IF ELSE statement or CASE WHEN statement. i.e. [at]itemCount < 1, it will insert new row, if not, select a particular column in the table.

Comment: Can use it anywhere you can use a value.  `IF @itemCount < 1 THEN INSERT ... ELSE UPDATE .... END IF;`  `CASE @itemCount WHEN 0 THEN .... ELSE .... END`