# MySQL select query with where condition using string variables

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

Myself trying to pass string variable to where condition in MySQL query as given in this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/declare-a-variable-in-mysql) as given below.

```
select @start := ' and  Id=21';

select * from myTable where 1=1 @start;
```

So how can I use string variable with where condition in MySQL queries. The variables are set dynamically and the query runs within procedure.

**EDIT:** I also tried

```
SET @start = ' Id=21 ';

select * from myTable where (select @start);
```

But no use.

Comment: ... Wrap the string value in quotes?

Comment: No way.. I also tried both `SELECT` and `SET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you cannot do that. The columns and the condition in the select clause needs to be **fixed** when you are preparing the `select` statement.

So you cannot make a dynamic where clause statement like the one you [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/declare-a-variable-in-mysql). In that example, the values in the column are dynamic not the column names.

The manual says:

> A conditional object consists of one or more conditional fragments
>   that will all be joined by a specified conjunction. By default, that
>   conjunction is **AND**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are attempting is to create a Dynamic Query using EXEC command.

You can create a varchar variable with the SQL statement and then execute it with EXEC, here an example taken from

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

If you want to do something like

```
DECLARE @city varchar(75)

SET @city = 'London'

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE City = @city
```

This is the Dynamic Query creation.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)

DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)

DECLARE @city varchar(75)

SET @columnList = 'CustomerID, ContactName, City'

SET @city = '''London'''

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM customers WHERE City = ' + @city

EXEC (@sqlCommand) --This does the magic 


/*
just a heads up, the user impersonating the execution needs credentials for EXEC command.
*/
```

Comment: It's just that you must use not EXEC, but PREPARE and EXECUTE, because this question concerns MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Store part of your query

```
SET @start = ' and  Id=21';
```

Store your query concatenating its parts

```
SET @s = CONCAT('select * from myTable where 1=1 ', @start);
```

Prepare a statement for execution

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
```

EXECUTE executes a prepared statement

```
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Release the prepared statement

```
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

All together:

```
SET @start = ' and  Id=21';
SET @s = CONCAT('select * from myTable where 1=1 ', @start);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

More Details on the MySQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html