# How can I store the result of a query into a variable and use it multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a query *(trigger)* like this:

```
BEGIN     
    IF (new.edited_id IS NULL) THEN
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot ask anymore";
        ELSEIF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'10000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot answer anymore";
        END IF;
    ELSE 
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'100000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot edit anymore";
        END IF;
END
```

As you see, the conditions of those inner `IF` statements are almost the same. Well how can I improve it?

I mean, how can I store the result of following query into a variable:

```
SELECT active FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id;
```

And then use it into those conditions like these:

```
IF (IFNULL((@variable & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
IF (IFNULL((@variable & b'10000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
IF (IFNULL((@variable & b'100000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
```

How can I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a *[local variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html)* and set it with the output from select statement.

```
DECLARE v_active bit(10);
SET v_active := (SELECT active FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id);
```

Comment: `active` is of `BIT(10)` datatype.

Comment: I've changed the datatype.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. Just for my information, what happens if you don't `DECLARE` a variable and `SET` it something? I mean what's the default *datatype*?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11754790/2095534) should help you. Local variables and user-defined variables are different thing.

Comment: I see. So why did you suggest I have to use `local variable`? Why not `user-defined` variable?

Comment: This is because you only need it to be visible inside the stored procedure itself. User-defined variables are available in different statements while local aren't.