# How to pre-set MySQL user variables in config files

Tags: mysql

MySQL allows usage of User-defined variables [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql) 
Is there a way for me to pre-set one such constant, so that it's automatically ready to use in PHP scripts, CLI clients and whatnot? As if every session were automatically started with a
    `SET @whatever = 2.52;`

Comment: Thus isn't a systems administration problem, it's a programming/design problem.

Comment: Really, I have been programming daily since the Eighties, I hold a doctorate in computer science and I am a CTO for two separate hi-tech companies. I know that I could store the value in a table. It would cost us a lot in execution time, though. I get that the question sounds like a newbie's. It's really not. I would be grateful if everybody stopped questioning my motives and my sanity and told me if it's possible, from a systems administration standpoint, to set up a MySQL user-defined variable in a config file.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. May I ask you to add this line to your main answer below, so that I may flag it as correct and definitive?

Answer (score 4):

Create a table, that keeps this value and select from it everywhere, when you need it. That will be a simple subselect in sql queries.

Comment: Yeah, well, a simple subselect can wreak havoc in my complex queries made by joining tables with millions of records. That's way I was looking for a queryless workaround…

Comment: Then implement these queries as service and provide that service with configuration file.

Comment: Variables are session scoped. So you can execute sql's, that set variables from select. And later use them as variables in other sqls.