# How to create stored procedure that inserts both input and data from select statement after first insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL that will add rows to two different tables. The first table (sites) has an id column set to auto_increment which I would like to include in the second insert statement to the sitesByUser table. I've tried some ideas based off this excellent post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql but I get various errors, such as the one listed below. I suspect that part of my problem is that I'm trying to both add both `userInput` and `SELECT id FROM sites WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()` to the same table, but I'm not sure what to do to get that to work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createSite(IN siteName VARCHAR(2048), IN userInput VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sites(siteName, user) VALUES (siteName, userInput);
INSERT INTO sitesByUser(user, site) userInput, SELECT id FROM sites WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT * FROM sitesByUser WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

The response from MySQL:

```
Error while performing Query.
ER_PARSE_ERROR
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userInput, SELECT id FROM sites WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT * FROM sitesBy' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the correct way to do this is to store the LAST_INSERT_ID() in a variable as described here: [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql) I'm not sure that I should be using the @ symbol in front of the variable since that seems to make it a user-defined variable which means it is session-specific which is probably too wide in scope for my needs, but so far, this successfully creates a stored procedure that I think will work. I'll update this post if it does not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createSite(IN siteName VARCHAR(2048), IN userInput VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO sites(siteName, user) VALUES (siteName, userInput);
SET @last_id_in_sites = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO sitesByUser(user, site) VALUES (userInput, @last_id_in_sites);
SELECT * FROM sitesByUser WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT * FROM sitesByUser WHERE id=@last_id_in_table1;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: was it helpful?