# Need to find total (sum) from 5pm on one day to 5am on the next day in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table for data containing earnings for taxi / uber rides with the following fields:

```
id
ride_date 
ride_earnings
ride_tips
```

I am trying to get a list of the most "profitable" dates, I can do:

```
SELECT DATE(ride_date) as d, SUM(ride_earnings+ride_tips) as total, COUNT(id) as ride_count 
FROM rides 
GROUP by d 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

But I need to group them as all rides from 12pm on one day - 12pm the next day. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Changed from 12p - 12p to make it more simple

EDIT2: Also, I should have stated this but i will be pulling this data through PHP so I would preferably need it in one statement

Comment: can you show us example result data ?

Comment: If `ride_date` is a DATE data taype, there is no way to know if it was bofore or after `5am` or `5pm`.

Comment: `ride_date` is a DATETIME field that would look like `2018-01-01 05:59:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    DATE(ride_date - interval 5 hour) as d,
    SUM(ride_earnings+ride_tips) as total,
    COUNT(id) as ride_count
FROM rides
WHERE time(ride_date) >= '17:00:00' 
   OR time(ride_date) <= '05:00:00' 
GROUP by d
order by total DESC
```

`DATE(ride_date - interval 5 hour)` will count the morning hours (0:00 - 5:00) to the day before. The WHERE clause will ensure that only rides from 17:00 - 24:00 and from 00:00 - 05:00 will be counted.

#### Update

**Note:** Please don't change your question in a way that would invalidate given answers.

```
SELECT
    DATE(ride_date - interval 12 hour) as d,
    SUM(ride_earnings+ride_tips) as total,
    COUNT(id) as ride_count
FROM rides
GROUP by d
order by total DESC
```

Here the first 12 hours of the day will be counted to the day before. The WHERE clause is not needed in this case.

Comment: I will try this , If I wanted to to 12p - 12p should I just change those values in the WHERE clause or would I need to change the interval too?

Comment: @TheJoester What does "12p - 12p" mean? But I guess: Yes - you need do change the interval too.

Comment: sorry, I meant for the range of 12pm one day to 12pm the following day.

Comment: The second Query worked perfect! Sorry about changing the question I thought it would help. I can see how it does not.

Comment: This answer saved my time

Answer (score 0):

make a temporary table containing the dates you need to group by. eg.(t_sql syntax) :

```
declare @startDate date, @endDate.
select @startDate=min(ride_date), @endDate=max(ride_date) from rides


declare @tempDate date=dateAdd(dd,-1,@startDate)
declare @dateIntervals table(starDT dateTime, endDT dateTime)
while(@tempDate<@endDate) begin
    insert into @dateIntervals
    values(cast(@tempDate as DateTime)+'05:00:00',cast(dateAdd(dd,1,@tempDate) as DateTime)+'05:00:00')
    select @tempDate=dateAdd(dd, 1,@tempDate)
end

select t1.startDT as d, SUM(ride_earnings+ride_tips) as total, COUNT(id) as ride_count 
from @dateIntervals t1
left join rides t2 on t2.ride_date>=t1.startDT and t2.ridetDate<t2.endDT
GROUP by d 
order by total DESC
```

Comment: `1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "declare" at position 0)`

Comment: @TheJoester https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
SELECT DATE(ride_date) as d, SUM(ride_earnings+ride_tips) as total, COUNT(id) as ride_count FROM rides 
WHERE HOUR(ride_date) < 17 AND HOUR(ride_date) > 5
GROUP by d order by total DESC
```

Comment: `HOUR(ride_date) > 17 AND HOUR(ride_date) < 5` - This is impossible.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Could you at least explain why?

Comment: Are you kidding? Tell me one number that is > 17 and < 5

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks, I corrected my answer, there's no necessity to be a jerk

Comment: "there's no necessity to be a jerk" - I see you try not to be. But your change still doesn't match the requirement: "from 5pm on one day - 5am the next day".

Comment: I tried this but it seems to be grouping rides from 00:00:00 - 05:00:00 with rides from 17:00:00 - 23:59:59 on the same day still.

Comment: But the 0-5 hours would belong to the previous day, and 17-23 hours to that day, right?, sorry, I think I can't completely understand you problem hehehe

Comment: my initial question made it more difficult than it needs to be. lets say for simplicity sake I want to get the sum of all rides from 12pm to 12pm the following day