# Creating a stored function in SQL to check if a year is a leap year or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if the problem lies in my logic, or incorrect use of syntax :/

Gives the error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Answer = "Leap Year";
  ELSE SET Answer = "Not a Leap Year";"

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_Leap_Year; 

CREATE FUNCTION f_Leap_Year(ENTER_YEAR INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)

BEGIN

  DECLARE Answer VARCHAR(30);
  DECLARE ENTER_YEAR INTEGER;

  If (Enter_Year % 400 = 0
  OR (Enter_Year % 4 =0 and not Enter_Year % 100 = 0))
  SET Answer = "Leap Year";
  ELSE SET Answer = "Not a Leap Year";

  RETURN Answer;

END $$
```

Comment: The name of the variable needs to start with an @ sign.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11754790/4180382

Answer (score 4):

This is a redundant function. Here's why...

```
SET @year = '2016';

SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(@year,'-03-01') - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%d') = 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_leap;
+---------+
| is_leap |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on Strawberry's answer. 
it is also possible without using `- INTERVAL 1 DAY` because `DATE_FORMAT('2015-02-29', '%d')` will generate a NULL value when it is a invalid date.

**Queries**

```
  SET @year = '2015';
  SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(@year, '-02-29'), "%d") IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_leap;

  SET @year = '2016';
  SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(@year, '-02-29'), "%d") IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_leap;
```

**Results**

```
+---------+
| is_leap |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+

+---------+
| is_leap |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

**demo**

http://rextester.com/NQB35930

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. In fact, I think the problem was that I was missing `THEN` from each of the `SET` statements, and a `DETERMINISTIC`; the code below worked.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS LeapYear;

CREATE FUNCTION LeapYear(EnterYear INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

  DECLARE answer VARCHAR(35);

  IF (Enter_Year % 400 = 0
  OR (Enter_Year % 4 =0 and not Enter_Year % 100 = 0)) THEN 
  SET answer = 'Leap year';
  ELSE
  SET answer = 'Not a leap year';
  END IF;

 RETURN (answer);
END
```

But now I have a new problem - while I can create the function and it shows up as existing within the database, when I try to use it, I get the following error:

```
MariaDB [my_dbname]> select leapyear(1976)$$
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Enter_Year' in 'field list'
```

It seems to think I am trying to select a column rather than calling a function  - does anyone know why this might be happening?