# Declaring a variable in MySQL with multiple JOIN tables

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, declare

I am trying to get a resulting column of the initial month an ID was created where multiple table JOINs are needed in MySQL Workbench.

```
SET @in_month = '0';

SELECT 
    ca.id
FROM capital.user ca
    JOIN 
    capital.user_account cd on ca.id = cd.user_id
    JOIN
    capital.transaction ct on cd.user_id = ct.user_account_id
    JOIN
    capital.transaction_event ce on ct.id = ce.auth_entry_id 

  @in_month = month(ce.created) WHERE ce.message = 'Approved'

Group by id;
```

I get Syntax error: '@in_month' (at text suffix) is not valid input at this position on line 17, any ideas of what I might be doing wrong? I don't have a lot of experience with SQL

Comment: update your question with detailed error message that you have got

Comment: user semicolon(;) after your variable declaration

Comment: Have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you are missing semicolon after variable declaration & and on join condition

```
    SET @in_month = '0';

    SELECT 
        ca.id
    FROM capital.user ca
    JOIN capital.user_account cd on ca.id = cd.user_id
    JOIN capital.transaction ct on cd.user_id = ct.user_account_id
    JOIN capital.transaction_event ce on ct.id = ce.auth_entry_id  and 
         @in_month = month(ce.created) 
    WHERE ce.message = 'Approved'
    Group by id;
```

Comment: with the semicolons I get "error : invalid input at this position" at lines  1 and 17

Comment: you are also missing the semicolon at declare statement thats why its throwing an error . i have updated code .. look at them

Comment: Syntax error: 'Declare' (declare) is not valid input at this position on line 1 and Syntax error: '@in_month' (at text suffix) is not valid input at this position on line 17

Comment: you dont have to do this    DECLARE @in_month INT; in your code...just check it out

Comment: I see what you mean Ankit, I have removed line 1. Unfortunately I still get the same syntax error not valid input at this position on line 17.. now line 16. @in_moth = month(ce.created) WHERE ce.message = 'Approved'