# passing parameter to mysql source statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to source simple mysql statement from a file. But it is giving an error. Below is my code -

```
@srcpath='/home/work/onlinemarket/databaseScripts/'; 
SET @c = CONCAT(@srcpath,  'adtype.sql');
source @c;
```

And it is giving following error,

```
Failed to open file ''@c'', error: 2
```

any pointer to resolve this error will be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Does the variables need that @ ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Comment: if you we dont give @ in 'source @c', it will give 'Failed to open file ''c'', error: 2