# MySQL IF statement really not like Sql Server

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to translate this Sql Server statement into MySQL

```
IF(SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable) = 0 THEN
// Do Something
ELSE
// Do Another Thing
```

I just can't make it work.

I can't even make some variables do their job.
MySQL help isn't helpfull at all.

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what *Do Something* look like ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also can you answer Khalid's question?  Thanks!

Comment: `IF((SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable) = 0, /* Do Something */, /* Do Another Thing */)`

Comment: If statements of this kind are only allowed in stored programs(procedures,function,triggers,events) in mysql is your code in any of these?

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html, confusingly (perhaps) there is also  a control flow function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html and this is worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    IF(
        someVal = CURRENT_DATE(),
        'output when true',
        'output when false'
    ) AS someResult,
    col2
FROM foo
WHERE
    IF(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo) = 0,
        ...,
        ...
    );
```

This should be enough for you to understand how to do it properly ;)