# How to make variable interval condition query with join

Tags: mysql, subquery, intervals

I have two MySQL tables.

```
test_settings 
id, interval_in_minutes, other_irrevelant_settings

test_results
id, test_settings_id(Foregin Key), datetime, value
```

I would like to run query `every 1 minute` and run tests which last result was later than `interval_in_minutes` for every individual test.

Sample db data

```
test_settings
id interval_in_minutes
1 10 
2 40
3 140
etc
```

So finally result of query will be `id 3` if there was no result inserted for last 140 minutes (based on `test_result` `datetime` inserted after test).

```
SELECT ts.id
FROM test_settings ts
WHERE (SELECT tr.date
       FROM test_results tr
       WHERE tr.test_settings_id = tr.id
       ORDER BY tr.datetime DESC
       LIMIT 1) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL XXXXX MINUTES);
```

It works only if interval is like `XXXXX = 4` but I need it to be dynamic like `XXXXX = ts.interval_in_minutes`.

No idea how to do it.. Any help?

Comment: simply declare variable
and use that

Comment: Please have look in this @nomysz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Comment: @D-johnAnshani thanks for reply, I tried few combinations but everytime sql syntax error near INTERVAL (like `INTERVAL @interv MINUTES`). Can you suggest usage in query?

Comment: When you are using store procedure at that time its more usable sp work like a function you can pass values in parameter and then it will used as dynamically @nomysz

Comment: Ok I found simpler way by implementing conditions in code (maybe slightly worse in performance).

Comment: Ok so your problem is now resolve or still pending??

Comment: I dont know how to use it. Tried few combinations with no luck.

I resolved it by changing logic so now query is simple but app has to do some work instead of db engine.

My problem is resolved but my question not.

Comment: I need to check more deeply maybe with some other resource