# SQL Median Value Undeclared Variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure to obtain the median age within a table but am getting an undeclared variable error. My code is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MedianAge()
BEGIN

SET @row_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee);
SET @median_index = (@row_count/2);

SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bdate, CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM employee ORDER BY bdate DESC 
LIMIT median_index, median_index;


END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am receiving the error:

```
Error Code: 1327. Undeclared variable: median_index
```

As far as I am aware I have declared the variable correctly and am unsure why the SELECT statement does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using user-defined variables (prefixed with @). However, within the stored procedures you should use local variables (with no prefix). These variables have to be declared prior to use. The difference is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11754790/4732334).

You would get something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MedianAge()
BEGIN

DECLARE row_cnt INT unsigned;
DECLARE median_index INT unsigned;

SET row_cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees);
SET median_index = (row_cnt/2);

SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bdate, CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM employee ORDER BY bdate DESC 
LIMIT median_index, median_index;


END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Also, keep in mind that row_count is a reserved word in MySQL (a function name). It's better to avoid using it as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference, that is understood now. I am also getting error code 1064 trying to implement `DECLARE row_cnt INT unsigned;`

Comment: The code above worked just fine for me. Are you sure that the error arises for the row_cnt declaration?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue was, I attempted again and it's working perfectly. Thanks very much for your assistance. I will mark this as correct.

Comment: Glad it helped!