# Unknown system variable when creating procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to create a stored procedure and using select in while statement. This query will come to this error `"unknown system variable 'tableview'"`. Anyone help me please to repair it. Thanks for your helping.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tablebts()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    SET x=0;
    SET tableview;

    WHILE x < 10 DO
        SET x=x + 1;
        SET tableview = SELECT idbts 
                        FROM (SELECT idbts, namesite, COUNT(idbts) AS jumlah 
                              FROM (SELECT ts.site_id AS idbts, tps.msisdn AS msisdn, tb.site_name AS namesite 
                                    FROM tb_profile_subscribers tps
                                    INNER JOIN tb_sitemap ts 
                                       ON tps.lac=ts.lac2g 
                                       or tps.lac=ts.lac3g 
                                      AND tps.cellid=ts.ci2g 
                                       OR tps.cellid=ts.ci3g_850 
                                       OR tps.cellid=ts.ci3g_2100_1
                                       OR tps.cellid=ts.ci3g_2100_2 
                                       OR tps.cellid=ts.ci3g_2100_3 
                                    INNER JOIN tb_bts tb 
                                       ON ts.site_id=tb.site_id 
                                    GROUP BY msisdn) msisdn 
                              GROUP BY idbts 
                              ORDER BY jumlah DESC 
                              LIMIT 1 OFFSET x) AS tabelbts
    END WHILE;

    SELECT tableview;
END$$
```

I also put x variable in `tableview` query (the word "offset x"). Is that true? Help me please and thanks in advance

Comment: You forget `DECLARE tableview INT;`?

Comment: Like @SalmanA said you forgot to declare the `tableview` property. But whats your goals with this query? Because you override constantly the `tableview` variable and so basically you only return the 10th record?

Comment: If you return a value, it would be better to create a `FUNCTION`

Comment: You may find this a useful read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Comment: @Salman A I don't wanna make the table view as integer, it looks like a create view of table. There's no problem when I try the select query, the problem when I make it a while for looping the offset in that query. Do you have another suggestion without using procedure?

Comment: @Yoram, sorry I was wrong. It's not set query but set tableview and it's still wrong

Comment: @Gaborsch okay I'll try. Thanks for ur suggestion

Comment: You appear to be attempting to create a table but MYSQL: does not have table variables , the closest mysql gets is temporary tables.

Comment: @P.Salmon should I declare the database name too although I have use syntax use databasename?

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for the link

Comment: @P.Salmon should I make a create view table?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do so the best I can say is maybe.

Comment: @P.Salmon okay, thanks for ur helping

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks, I'm so sorry. But at least I have solved this problem. Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

Not related to your problem but there are somethings you need to fix too.

- You have to use parenthesis to force correct operator order

Right now you have `A OR B AND C OR D` Because `AND` have precedence you really have

```
 A OR ( B AND C ) OR D
```

instead you need

```
(A OR B) AND (C OR D)
```

- Or you can use `IN` operator to improve reading

  ```
  INNER JOIN tb_sitemap ts 
     ON tps.lac IN ( ts.lac2g, ts.lac3g )
    AND tps.cellid IN ( ts.ci2g, ts.ci3g_850, ts.ci3g_2100_1, 
                        ts.ci3g_2100_2, ts.ci3g_2100_3 )
  ```

Comment: Thanks for ur helping. But there's no problem about select query. It's success to view a table. The problem is just about looping the offset value (x). Do u have any suggestion? Thanks before

Comment: But in the brackets u have explained me, just be used for "AND". I make it as "OR"