# How to declare variable in mysql 8.0.16?

Tags: mysql, parse-error

I created a stored procedure when I tried to declare a variable to store the returned data from the procedure it gives me declaration error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare counter int call country(101, counter out) print counter' at line 1

This is the command that I used to declare and store the procedure output:

```
declare counter int
call country_counter(101,counter out)
print counter
```

It shows red line under **declare** keyword

This is the used procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `country_counter`(
cntr_code int,
OUT cntr int
)
BEGIN
select cntr = count(id) from users where country_code = cntr_code;
END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Any idea?

Comment: I doubt if you can use `DECLARE` syntax outside a `begin.. end` block. To declare variables outside `begin ..end` block, `SET ..` syntax is generally used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: @altouq Is first one an another stored procedure?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek i have one and only procedure, look at it above

Comment: declare counter int
call country(101,counter out)
print counter ....is it part of same procedure?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek i just edited the code i was mean country_counter procedure **NOT** country procedure the code above is working with the procedure above too, take a look again

Comment: did you close statement before 'declare counter int' using semocolon ?