# MySQL: How to check if a word appears more than once in a string

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-workbench

I have a table with three column say: `name`,`flag`, and `value`, where `name` is a primary key of type string, `flag` contains integer, and `value` contains a LONGTEXT.

The LONGTEXT contains strings which may contains a word that can appear multiple times.

I know that I can search for specific string using LIKE. But I want to query the rows where a specific word say `my-word` appear more than once, and I want to know how many times it appeard (2,3, etc.) in each cell?

Is this possible?

Comment: use replace() to remove the word from the longtext.  then subtract the length of the original from the one with the word removed and divide by the number of characters in the word.

Comment: (@xQbert - Make your Comment into an Answer.)

Comment: @xQbert Can you plz check my answer? If correct, can you comment and up vote if you like :)

Comment: @RickJames  Normally I would but I was in a hurry and didn't actually write up a valid/complete answer.  So instead my comment was intended to provide a possible direction to consider.  I didn't feel it was a complete answer just a good idea to try.  I'm also really happy that none was able to take the idea and build it themself!

Answer (score 2):

The query should be like this:

```
select value, (length(value)-length(replace(value,'my-word','')))/7
from mytable
where value like '%my-word%'
```

I divide by 7 because the word `my-word` contains 7 characters. So the number you divide by should be the number of characters of the word you want to count how many times it appeared.

Comment: My only comment would be to use a variable instead of hard coding the value and the length of 7.  Or alternatively; use a procedure and pass in a paramater.  Possibilities defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Comment: I'd also alias the calculated column for easier reference.  `WordOccurances` or something.

Comment: Or simply change `/7` by `/length('my-word')`