# MySql use variable in WHERE

Tags: mysql, variables, mysql-variables

When I write code:

```
SET @code = 'a123';
UPDATE my_table SET number = (number + 1) WHERE code = @code;
```

it doesn't work correctly.
But if I write code:

```
UPDATE my_table SET number = (number + 1) WHERE code = 'a123';
```

it works correctly.
I want to use variable in "WHERE".
how can I use it?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Comment: @Marwen Jaffel I check it but doesn't work again

Comment: Is your SET & UPDATE queries within same transaction? If it does not try to wrap them into START TRANSACTION; SET ...; UPDATE ...; COMMIT;

Comment: What do you mean under "it does not work"? Throws error? Not updating record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests I came to the conclusion that I should to change the code like this:

```
SET @code = 'a123';
SET @mid = NULL;
SELECT @mid := id, @code := code FROM my_table WHERE code = @code;
UPDATE my_table SET number = (number + 1) WHERE id = @mid;
```

I should use 'id' instead of 'code' after 'WHERE' in UPDATE transaction

also I should to set @code in SELECT transaction again (why? I don't know!)

This code works correctly and the previous code doesn't work correctly and I don't know the reason!