# Continuously SQL to a Point

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a continuously SQL until reach max ID.

```
INSERT INTO creature_classlevelstats (`level`, `class`) 
VALUES 
(101, 1),
(101, 2),
(101, 4),
(101, 8),
(102, 1),
(102, 2),
(102, 4),
(102, 8),
(103, 1),
(103, 2),
(103, 4),
(103, 8),
(104, 1),
(104, 2),
(104, 4),
(104, 8);
```

This is example of what i'll be doing, sadly that this will be long since the max can be 255.
I have Tried this :

```
DECLARE @lvl INT
SET @lvl = 101
WHILE (@lvl <= 255)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO creature_classlevelstats (`level`, `class`) values 
(101, 1),
(101, 2),
(101, 4),
(101, 8);
SELECT @lvl = @lvl + 1
END
```

This is the Error

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'DECLARE @lvl INT

Comment: imho you miss to create a procedure to wrap the code into if you are using mysql

Comment: Seems like it is tho the reason is i don't understand the procedure or how i'll be finding the code on later..

Comment: Regarding the error please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this (WHILE has to be in a proc or function, and you don't need to DECLARE):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test()
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

    SET @lvl = 101;
    WHILE (@lvl <= 255) DO
     INSERT INTO creature_classlevelstats (`level`, `class`) values 
        (@lvl, 1),
        (@lvl, 2),
        (@lvl, 4),
        (@lvl, 8);
        SET @lvl = @lvl + 1;
    END WHILE;

END $$


DELIMITER ;

CALL test()
```

Comment: Excuse my bad but where could i find the PROCEDURE test i means i see the SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS; but sadly don't know how to find the result.

Comment: @JadaDeveloper the result of this procedure will be that the rows are inserted in your table. How is "show procedure status" related to this code?

Comment: I think you mean "how to use this procedure ?" in this case : - Create the procedure with the above statement (it will be called "test" unless you change it). Then open a new window and write "CALL test". This will call the procedure to be executed.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Nothing was inserted to the table. no errors tho.

Comment: @CyrilRebreyend When i did that it inserted only 101 and gives me duplication error.

Comment: @JadaDeveloper that's probably because you have defined as unique the value in the level and you are trying to insert multiple times the 101 value. The procedure works but the second insert is dropping an error for duplicate key on level field

Comment: Modified the code to make it work (changed SELECT to SET). Sorry.

Comment: @CyrilRebreyend Exactly that was the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select 1 as lev
      union all
      select lev + 1
      from cte
      where lev < 255
     )
insert into creature_classlevelstats (level, class) 
    select 100 + cte.lev, d.class  
    from (select 1 as class union al
          select 2 union all
          select 4 union all
          select 8
         ) d cross join
         cte;
```

Comment: This doesn't work sadly, insert into creature_classlevelstats (`level`, `class`) 
    select d.`level`

Comment: Looking at the comments on the other answer that's because of the duplicate entry constrain you probably have on level field

Comment: @JadaDeveloper . . . Include the columns that *you* want in the final table.  This answer is based on YOUR question.

Comment: @LelioFaieta  Well it wasn't unique level means level can be 101  - class 1 and 101 - class 2 and 101 class 4 etc.... without any issues of duplication the dup i mentioned was about the PROCEDURE test it was duplicated.

Comment: @JadaDeveloper . . . I was looking at your `while` loop.  In any case, what you want is even simpler than what I started with.