# OUT parameter declaration in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Excuse me for the pretty simple question, but I can't understand what I have to do from similar questions.

I have this code, It works but I got asked to insert input value for CountMacro1, CountMacro2, CountMacro3, CountMacro4, which is always 0. How can I explain to mysql that I want those variables set to 0? set @CountMacro1 = 0; seems not to work, why? Thanks everyone :D

Mysql workbench do a call and a select like this:

```
set @CountMacro1 = 0;
set @CountMacro2 = 0;
set @CountMacro3 = 0;
set @CountMacro4 = 0;
call dbcbt.CountMacro_Audit_Scaduti(@CountMacro1, @CountMacro2, @CountMacro3, @CountMacro4);
select @CountMacro1, @CountMacro2, @CountMacro3, @CountMacro4;
```

Thats the call in php:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dbcbt", $username, $password);


$sql = 'CALL CountMacro_Audit_Scaduti(@CountMacro1_OUT,@CountMacro2_OUT,@CountMacro3_OUT,@CountMacro4_OUT)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$CountMacro1_OUT = 0;
$CountMacro2_OUT = 0;
$CountMacro3_OUT = 0;
$CountMacro4_OUT = 0;

$stmt->bindParam(1, $CountMacro1_OUT, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $CountMacro2_OUT, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $CountMacro3_OUT, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $CountMacro4_OUT, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);

print "Values of bound parameters _before_ CALL:\n";
print "  1: {$CountMacro1_OUT} 2: {$CountMacro2_OUT} 3: {$CountMacro3_OUT} 4: {$CountMacro4_OUT}\n";

$stmt->execute();

print "Values of bound parameters _after_ CALL:\n";
print "  1: {$CountMacro1_OUT} 2: {$CountMacro2_OUT} 3: {$CountMacro3_OUT} 4: {$CountMacro4_OUT}\n";
```

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CountMacro_Audit_Scaduti`(
OUT CountMacro1 int,
OUT CountMacro2 int,
OUT CountMacro3 int,
OUT CountMacro4 int
)
BEGIN
set @CountMacro1 = 0;
set @CountMacro2 = 0;
set @CountMacro3 = 0;
set @CountMacro4 = 0;

select count(*)
INTO CountMacro1
from t_audit
WHERE (t_audit.Data_Scadenza < NOW()) AND (t_audit.Data_Completamento ="" OR t_audit.Data_Completamento is null) AND (t_audit.Macro1= 1 OR t_audit.Macro2= 1 OR t_audit.Macro3= 1);

select count(*)
INTO CountMacro2
from t_audit
WHERE t_audit.Data_Scadenza < NOW() AND (t_audit.Data_Completamento ="" OR t_audit.Data_Completamento is null) AND (t_audit.Macro1= 2 OR t_audit.Macro2= 2 OR t_audit.Macro3= 2);

select count(*)
INTO CountMacro3
from t_audit
WHERE t_audit.Data_Scadenza < NOW() AND (t_audit.Data_Completamento ="" OR t_audit.Data_Completamento is null) AND (t_audit.Macro1= 3 OR t_audit.Macro2= 3 OR t_audit.Macro3= 3);

select count(*)
INTO CountMacro4
from t_audit
WHERE t_audit.Data_Scadenza < NOW() AND (t_audit.Data_Completamento ="" OR t_audit.Data_Completamento is null) AND (t_audit.Macro1= 4 OR t_audit.Macro2= 4 OR t_audit.Macro3= 4);

END
```

Comment: User defined(at varaibles) and declared variables are not the same thing please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can declare Local variables and then you can assign the default value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROC(var OUT) 
BEGIN   
   DECLARE CountMacro1 INT DEFAULT 0;  
   DECLARE CountMacro2 INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE CountMacro3 INT DEFAULT 0;  
   DECLARE CountMacro4 INT DEFAULT 0;
   --Your code
END;
```

In your case, you are trying to assign default value to `@CountMacro1` which is  [User defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and in your query you are assigning the count to local variable `CountMacro1`. Both are different.

You can run the below procedure to see the difference

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_test ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE CountMacro1  INT DEFAULT 1;
    SET @CountMacro1  = 2;
    SELECT  CountMacro1 , @CountMacro1 ;
END;
```

OUTPUT

```
+-------------+--------------+
| CountMacro1 | @CountMacro1 |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1           | 2            |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: THX for the answer, I understand that CountMacro1 is different from @CountMacro1.  Where CountMacro1 is the local variable. But why when I insert 0,0,0,0 manually as imput values ( from the mysql workbench) I got the correct count output? 
In addition I tried "DECLARE CountMacro1 INT DEFAULT 0; " but he still ask me to imput values.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get your point. I have created a similar procedure here -> [CLICK THIS DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cdeacd70bac986d28e9a6e5cb84774c2) and it is working fine. I'm able to get the `default` value for `CountMacro2`. Can you please replicate your issue here? @DomenicoSchitti

Comment: The problem is that when I run the procedure I still get this input box where he ask me to insert the values: https://ibb.co/Rz5t82t. Sorry but I cant understand how to change it D:, I just want my procedure to give in output my four row count in four variables.

Comment: How are you calling the procedure? Are you running both `call()` and `select` together? [Check this link once](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/591329/Solved-Execute-Stored-Procedure-with-Output-Parameter-in-MySql-database/)

Comment: I'm testing it on the workbench clicking on the lighting button next to the stored procedure name, the program do a call and a select, like Im writing up, in the question.

Comment: This looks strange. What happens when you run manually `call` and `select`? instead of lighting button? @DomenicoSchitti

Comment: He asks for input numbers and I have to insert "0" in the four text boxes. I tried to call the stored procedure in php but I get always "0" as output. In the bench after that I fill the text boxes I get the correct values in output. I'm showing the php script in the question.