# Stored procedure, using variable no result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The variable `@total` in `DESC LIMIT ?` isn't working. If I manually set `DESC LIMIT 3` then the sp runs fine and returns rows. I also tried placing the `SET total`  in between `PREPARE`.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE getTotalNET()
BEGIN

DECLARE total INT;

SET total := (SELECT COUNT(*) as item_count FROM items WHERE hostid = '12345' and key_ LIKE '%_net%' AND STATUS = '0' );

PREPARE STMT FROM
 " SELECT DISTINCT itemid, clock, VALUE, ns FROM history_uint WHERE itemid IN (SELECT itemid FROM items WHERE hostid = '12345' and key_ LIKE '%_net%'  AND STATUS = '0' ) AND clock >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 120 SECOND) ORDER BY clock DESC LIMIT ?";

EXECUTE STMT USING @total ;


END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: user defined variables (at variables) and declared variables are not the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql

Comment: Can you reply as  answer? I'll accept it as correct answer. @P.Salmon