# why mysql procedure return null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a simple mysql procedure which must return an query string. But, it returns almost every time `QueryResult` (column name) as `<null>` value.

```
create procedure return_table_rename_query(
  IN targetTable VARCHAR(100),
  IN tblPrefix VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    SET @returnQuery = CONCAT('SELECT "MYSQLIMPORT can not rename table for target ', @targetTable, '";');
    SET @totalRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table);
    if IFNULL(@totalRows, 0) > 0
        then
          SET @returnQuery = CONCAT('drop table if exists table_name.', ...);
    end if;

    SELECT @returnQuery AS 'QueryResult';
end;
```

Comment: solution was based on P.Salmon answer, which also is checked as solution. I don't think was needed to remove it.

Comment: We have a policy that a question should not be edited with a solution. If you have something to add on top of the accepted answer you can post an alternative answer, but do not edit it into the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@targettable is not the same variable as targettable - you are mixing user defined variables and parameter variables and it seems likely that @targettable is null and if any element in a concat is null then the result is null.

Please read [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql)