# how to create a function in mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, function, syntax

trying to get the total number of boxes ordered from a given type("mytype").
something seems to be wrong with my syntax

```
create function NumOrdersForBoxType (mytype varchar(20))
returns int
begin
DECLARE @numorders int 
  select @numOrders = count(*)
    from BOXES as B
    where B.Type = mytype
    return @numOrders
end
;
```

Comment: In mysql you don't declare user defined variables (at variables) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql AND every statement needs to be terminated and since you have more than 1 statement in the function you need to wrap in begin..end and possibly set delimiters. AND you need to SET variables.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you don't declare user defined variables (at variables) stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/… AND every statement needs to be terminated and since you have more than 1 statement in the function you need to wrap in begin..end and possibly set delimiters. AND you need to SET variables

```
delimiter $$

create function f(mytype varchar(20))
returns int
begin
DECLARE numorders int; 
    set numorders = (select count(*)
    from boxes as B
    where B.Type = mytype
    );
    return numOrders;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please provide sample data as text and explain why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: Please see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/FgiQTV271HxHWMyA5nTv7/0

Comment: am I not supposed to add the '@' before declaring a local variable?

Comment: Not in MySQL did you read the link in my comment