# How to declare a variable use DECLARE in mysql 8.0?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Today I learned how to decalre a variable from textbook and the code they give me is

`'DECLARE test_sql INT DEFAULT 10;'`

When I run this line I got an `error 1064 syntax` error.
How to fix my code?

Then I run `'SET @test_sql=30;'` and it works so are there any differences between these two codes and can I declare a  variable with a default value by using a SET sentence?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: The variable may be declared only in solid code block (BEGIN_END in function, stored procedure, etc.).