# I am not able to determine the proper syntax for a DBeaver MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, dbeaver

I am just trying to simply declare a variable with a default value that I will then use elsewhere in my script.  I have tried:

```
Declare @datasource varchar(10) default 'ABC';
Declare datasource varchar(10) default 'ABC';
```

I have even tried simply:

```
 Declare @datasource varchar(10);
```

It fails with a SQL Error [1064] every time.  I'm using DBeaver.  What am I missing?

Wrapped the declare in a procedure.  Still get the syntax error.

```
delimiter //
create procedure CleanPCB()
   begin 
     declare @datasource varchar(10) default 'ABC';
   end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: you need a function or procedure to declare variables

Comment: I wrapped the same commands in a procedure.  Same result.  I'll add the completed code to the question.

Comment: Try: `set @datasource =  'ABC';  select @datasource;` as mentioned in [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: BTW: That is how it's used in the docs too, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

Comment: @muncieharts remove the add variable, read the duplicate link it is very comprehensive

Comment: Three tips, please follow all three:  You must not use `@` for variables when you use `DECLARE`. `DECLARE` can be used only within a `BEGIN...END` block. It must be the first statement after the first `BEGIN`.