# Function not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, hierarchical-data, varchar

I have a hierarchical relational database with taxonomies of different organisms.
I have a total of 7 tables where each has a FK pointing to the table "right above".
I need to create a function that recieves the "Common Name" of the organism and returns the Kindgom to whom it belongs. Below is my code on MySQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_Kingdom(@Temp AS VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) 
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnKingdom AS VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @ReturnKingdom = (SELECT kingdom.description as descriptionKingdom
                        FROM Kingdom
                        JOIN Phylum
                        ON Kingdom.idKingdom = phylum.Kingdom_idKingdom
                        JOIN Class
                        ON Phylum.idPhylum = Class.Phylum_idPhylum
                        JOIN Order
                        ON Class.idClass = Order.Class_idClass
                        JOIN Family
                        ON Order.idOrder = Family.Order_idOrder
                        JOIN Genus
                        ON Family.idFamily = Genus.Family_idFamily
                        JOIN Species
                        ON Genus.idGenus = Species.Genus_idGenus

                        WHERE Species.CommonName = @Temp)

    RETURN @ReturnKingdom;
END;
```

But when I try to call the function

```
select get_Kingdom('Dog');
```

I'm getting an error:

```
'fnc_get_reino' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The published code is not valid mysql you cannot declare user defined (@) variables. Drop the @ and code should compile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: After working on it, seems like the @ wasnt the problem, but rather the Call line. 


`select [dbo].[get_Kingdom]('Dog');`

This one seems to do the job just fine. Is it still incorrect syntaxis to have the "@" there? If I remove it I get a series of syntax errors.

Comment: dbo? I don't see that in the published code, together with the @ variables suggests you are working on sql-server/mssql rather than mysql , the syntax is quite different.