# Loop is not valid at this position expecting if

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, syntax

Having a couple of syntax errors in this code. I am having the "Loop is not valid at this position expecting if" at "loop", "statement is incomplete" at "END$" and "@commission is not valid at this position".

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE commissionCheck (IN employeeNum INT, INOUT commission VARCHAR(4000)) 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE employee_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT firstName,lastName,address,city,state,zipcode,sale
        FROM customer c, employee e, sale s, cityState cs
        WHERE s.employeeID = employeeNum;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
                FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
        OPEN employee_cursor;
        get_employee: LOOP
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_eFirst;
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_eLast;
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_eAddress;
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_eCity;
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_eState;
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_eZip;
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_retail;
         IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_employee;
        END IF;
        SET v_count = vcount + 1;
        SELECT v_eFirst;
        SELECT v_eLast;
        SELECT v_eAddress; 
        SELECT v_eCity; 
        SELECT v_eZip;
        SELECT v_retail;
        IF v_count = 1 THEN
            IF v_retail >= 40000 THEN SET v_pay = (v_retail * 0.20) + v_retail;
            ELSEIF v_retail >= 30000 THEN SET v_pay = (v_retail * 0.15) + v_retail;
            ELSEIF v_retail >= 20000 THEN SET v_pay = (v_retail * 0.10) + v_retail;
            ELSE SET  v_pay = (v_retail * 0.08) + v_retail;
            
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, 'FROM:\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\nCGS 2545 Car Dealership\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\UCF\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\MSB 260\n\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, 'Pay to the order of:\n\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, v_efirst, '', v_eLast,'\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, v_eAddress, '\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, v_eCity, ',', v_eState,'',v_eZip,'\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, 'In the amount of:\n\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '$', v_pay, '\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\n', v_lines, '\n');
        END IF;
        END LOOP get_employee;
        close employee_cursor;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SET @commission = "";
CALL @commission:{
    employeeId from sale
    @commission
}
SELECT @commission;
```

I havent really tried much to fix it to be honest. I am lost

Answer (score 0):

> Having a couple of syntax errors in this code.
> ...
> I haven't really tried much to fix it to be honest.

There's no need to be lost.
Just simplify your problem.

Currently you have a bunch of code, and a complex problem,
one that is too complex to understand how to fix it. Ok.

Simplify it.
Define a one-line function, see it *work*,
then a two-line function, and build up to
something that is roughly as long as what you posted.

Pay attention to the **small** change
you introduced which changes from green to red,
from working to not working.
Understand what that change does,
perhaps by consulting the documentation.

As it stands, you have a big blob of code that
neither you nor your readers understand.
Work on small problems, as they are easy to solve.

https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs

Answer (score 0):

1. you are missing an end if- I don't know where it should go so I guessed see #added...
2. local variables need to be declared [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql)
3. Having many fetchs looks wrong https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fetch.html.

This compiles but may not be logically what you want

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE P (IN employeeNum INT, INOUT commission VARCHAR(4000)) 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE v_eFirst VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE v_eLast VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE v_eAddress VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE v_eCity VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE v_eState VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE v_eZip VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE v_retail VARCHAR(10);
        DECLARE V_FINISHED INT;
        DECLARE v_count int;
        declare v_pay int;
        declare v_lines int;
    
        DECLARE employee_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT firstName,lastName,address,city,state,zipcode,sale
        FROM customer c, employee e, sale s, cityState cs
        WHERE s.employeeID = employeeNum;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
                FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
 
        OPEN employee_cursor;
        get_employee: LOOP
            FETCH employee_cursor INTO v_eFirst,
             v_eLast,
             v_eAddress,
             v_eCity,
             v_eState,
             v_eZip,
             v_retail;
             
        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_employee;
        END IF;
        SET v_count = vcount + 1;
        SELECT v_eFirst,v_eLast,v_eAddress,v_eCity,v_eZip, v_retail;
        
        IF v_count = 1 THEN
            IF v_retail >= 40000 THEN SET v_pay = (v_retail * 0.20) + v_retail;
            ELSEIF v_retail >= 30000 THEN SET v_pay = (v_retail * 0.15) + v_retail;
            ELSEIF v_retail >= 20000 THEN SET v_pay = (v_retail * 0.10) + v_retail;
            ELSE SET  v_pay = (v_retail * 0.08) + v_retail;
            end if; #added
            
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, 'FROM:\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\nCGS 2545 Car Dealership\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\UCF\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\MSB 260\n\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, 'Pay to the order of:\n\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, v_efirst, '', v_eLast,'\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, v_eAddress, '\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, v_eCity, ',', v_eState,'',v_eZip,'\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, 'In the amount of:\n\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '$', v_pay, '\n');
            SET commission = CONCAT(commission, '\n', v_lines, '\n');
        END IF;
  
        END LOOP;
        close employee_cursor;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```