# MySQL trigger error doesn't work because it needs a value from another table column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm new to the php mysql developpement, I want to make a trigger to be launched after I insert a row in the `evolution` table. The trigger must take a value (`prixMisDaccord`) from another table (`inscription`) and reduce it value from the `evolution` column `prixAPaye`.

Here is what I tried and what I found on Stack Overflow:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_rap
BEFORE INSERT ON evolution FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
       DECLARE pmd float;
       -- Check BookingRequest table
       SELECT prixMisDaccord
       INTO @pmd
       FROM inscription
       WHERE inscription.idETD= 1;

    
           
           SET NEW.resteAPaye = @pmd-NEW.prixPaye
           WHERE idETD = 1;
        
END;
$$
DELIMITER `;
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your trigger?

Comment: *The trigger must take a value (prixMisDaccord) from another table (inscription) and reduce it value from the evolution column prixAPaye.* Show this on an example. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: The trigger doesn't work i can't even create it it says that i have a probleme from this line SELECT prixMisDaccord

Answer (score 0):

'i have a probleme from this line SELECT' - Is not the error I get, I do get an error on the  set statement because you cannot apply a where clause to a set..There are other problems with your code and you don't seem to know the difference between user defined variables and declared variables see - [How to declare a variable in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql) and temporary tables..so @pmd-NEW.prixPaye is just nonsense.