select query inside MySQL stored procedure not working
My Stored Procedure  not working. here I want to display values for 12 months.
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_example;
delimiter //

CREATE procedure my_example()
wholeblock:BEGIN
  declare @amount double default 0.0;
  declare x INT default 0;
  SET x = 1;

  WHILE x <= 12 DO
    set @amount =  select sum(famount) as amount from grossitems as s where s.mmonth=x and s.myear=2023 and s.idnum='1117';
    SET x = x + 1;
    return amount;
end WHILE;
select amount;
END

If anyone can please help me to improve this.
I am expecting to show selected amount from table. There should be 12 records.

Your published code appears to be an invalid hybrid procedure/function..please review and I doubt that it actually compiles https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html . Not working is not a useful thing to say - if you have an error message publish it in full if it doesn't produce expected outcome add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754781/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-mysql


@amount and amount are two different variables. 2) set @amount =  select .. is incorrect. Study SELECT INTO. 3) There are more problems.


Why would you want to use a stored procedure when a simple group by query is so much simpler - select mmonth, sum(famount) as amount from grossitems where myear=2023 and idnum=1117 group by mmonth;?

To use a SELECT query as an expression you have to put it inside (): SET @amount = (SELECT ...). Or you can use SELECT SUM(...) INTO @amount FROM ...

If you use return amount inside the loop, the loop stops.

It seems like what you really want is a grouped query: SELECT mmonth, SUM(famount) AS amount FROM grossitems WHERE myear = 2023 and idnum = '1117' GROUP BY mmonth ORDER BY mmonth
